# How to have for loop that iterates through indexes as in objective-C (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a Google Maps app and I have the following code:

```
func drawPolygon(){
var cord: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []
let path = GMSMutablePath()
// get path for polygon
for marker in markersArray {
let lat = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][0]
let lng = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i+1] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][1]
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][0]))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][1]))
}
```

As you can see I would like to increment the index by one every time so all coordinates get inserted. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a build in mechanism for that.

```
func drawPolygon(){
var cord: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []
let path = GMSMutablePath()
// get path for polygon
for (marker, i) in markersArray.enumerated() {
let lat = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][0]
let lng = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i+1] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][1]
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][0]))
path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][1]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    func drawPolygon(){
    var cord: Array<CLLocationCoordinate2D> = []
    let path = GMSMutablePath()
    // get path for polygon
//initailizing i = 0;
    var i = 0
    for marker in markersArray {
    let lat = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][0]
    let lng = coord.insert(marker.componentsSeparatedByString(",")[i+1] as NSString).doubleValue, atIndex:[i][1]
    path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][0]))
    path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coord[i][1]))
//incrementing i with +1
    i = i+1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!